# Why is my pod stuck in PodInitializing after the init container is terminated for OOM?

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory, google-kubernetes-engine, argo-workflows

We are using Argo Workflows with GKE.
Sometimes, when the node runs out of memory one of the Init containers gets killed for OOM, and the pod is stuck in PodInitializing status.

Here is a sanitized example:

```
Name:         wf-7688-4275107272
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-prod-m32gi-c8-sa-work-e1438a2e-pmbj/10.132.0.173
Start Time:   Fri, 10 Mar 2023 11:01:31 +0200
Labels:       workflows.argoproj.io/completed=false
  workflows.argoproj.io/workflow=wf-7688
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: main
                kubernetes.io/limit-ranger:
                  LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container wait; cpu request for container main; cpu request for init container init; cpu request f...
                workflows.argoproj.io/node-id: wf-7688-4275107272
                workflows.argoproj.io/node-name: wf-7688(0)[0].wf-step51(0)
Status:       Failed
Reason:       Evicted
Message:      The node was low on resource: memory.
IP:           10.4.19.58
IPs:
  IP:           10.4.19.58
Controlled By:  Workflow/wf-7688
Init Containers:
  init:
    Container ID:  containerd://81d247f38262e258947086316bce5bb61e7bb75b8463186cf5bc9cb275fbeaab
    Image:         quay.io/argoproj/argoexec:v3.4.4
    Image ID:      quay.io/argoproj/argoexec@sha256:faf78d4a05ac219c4fe091733f17b2f802584f17109af870b79e6c4d748fa34e
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      argoexec
      init
      --loglevel
      info
      --log-format
      text
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 10 Mar 2023 11:01:36 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 10 Mar 2023 11:01:55 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      ARGO_POD_NAME:                      wf-7688-4275107272 (v1:metadata.name)
      ARGO_POD_UID:                        (v1:metadata.uid)
      GODEBUG:                            x509ignoreCN=0
      ARGO_WORKFLOW_NAME:                 wf-7688
      ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME:                init
      ARGO_TEMPLATE:                      ... An argo template that includes the following restart policy: "retryStrategy": {"limit": "5","retryPolicy": "Always","expression": "lastRetry.status == \"Error\" or (lastRetry.status == \"Failed\" and asInt(lastRetry.exitCode) not in [1,127])"},
      ARGO_NODE_ID:                       wf-7688-4275107272
      ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT:         false
      ARGO_DEADLINE:                      2023-03-12T09:01:21Z
      ARGO_PROGRESS_FILE:                 /var/run/argo/progress
      ARGO_PROGRESS_PATCH_TICK_DURATION:  1m0s
      ARGO_PROGRESS_FILE_TICK_DURATION:   3s
    Mounts:
      ...
  preparedata:
    Container ID:
    Image:         google/cloud-sdk:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      bash
      -c
    Args:
      ... bunch of shell commands ...

    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      ...
    Mounts:
      ...
Containers:
 ... 2 containers in WAITING status (PodInitializing)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  ...
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              nodetype=WORKFLOW
Tolerations:                 WORKFLOW=BASIC:NoSchedule
  node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
  node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

In such a scenario I'd like for the entire pod to terminate so it would be restarted.
First, I don't understand why the status of the terminated Init container has "Exit code" 0. Shouldn't it be 137?

Secondly, Is there a way to make the pod fail if one of the Init containers is terminated for OOM?

**EDIT 1**
Running `kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{.spec.restartPolicy}'` shows the restart policy is Never